# Google Charts Timeline - How to Force Bar Labels INSIDE of Bar

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google's charts library to generate a Gantt-like chart (using Timeline). One issue I am running into is the library's automatic `barLabel` placement. It's terribly inconsistent in when it should truncate long strings to put inside the label versus placing the full string **outside** of the label.

**Question**

How can I force text to always sit inside the bar?

**Example:**

[image: Example of text placement issue in Google Charts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

Required a little tweaking from @WhiteHat's response but here it is!

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        var rectangles = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
        var adjustY = 25;
        var adjustX = 15;
        for(var i=0; i<rectangles.length; i++){
            if (rectangles[i].getAttribute('x') !== '0') {
                var barLabel = container.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
                barLabel.innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(i, 1);
                barLabel.style.color = '#000';
                barLabel.style.position = 'absolute';
                barLabel.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                barLabel.style.width = (parseInt(rectangles[i].getAttribute('width') - adjustX)) + 'px';
                barLabel.style.top = (parseInt(rectangles[i].getAttribute('y')) + adjustY) + 'px';
                barLabel.style.left = (parseInt(rectangles[i].getAttribute('x')) + adjustX) + 'px';
            }
        }

    });

chart.draw(dataTable, {
    timeline: {
       showBarLabels: false
    }
});
```

Comment: This works but the text label will prevent the cell's tooltip to appear when you hover the mouse over the text.

Comment: barLabel.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; to fix the above issue

Answer (score 1):

since there isn't an option for "`alwaysInside`",

you could hide the labels with `timeline.showBarLabels: false`,

then add them manually when the chart is `'ready'`

the `<rect>` elements should be in the same order as the rows in the `dataTable`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['timeline']
});

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Row label' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Bar Label' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
    [ 'Row 1', 'Bar 1', new Date(2016, 7, 1, 0, 30), new Date(2016, 7, 1, 0, 35) ],
    [ 'Row 1', 'Bar 2', new Date(2016, 7, 1, 1, 15), new Date(2016, 7, 1, 1, 45) ],
    [ 'Row 1', 'Bar 3', new Date(2016, 7, 1, 1, 50), new Date(2016, 7, 1, 2, 15) ]
  ]);

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var index = 0;
    var adjustXY = 10;
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function (rect) {
      if (rect.getAttribute('x') !== '0') {
        var barLabel = container.appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
        barLabel.innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(index, 1);
        barLabel.style.color = '#ffffff';
        barLabel.style.position = 'absolute';
        barLabel.style.top = (parseInt(rect.getAttribute('y')) + adjustXY) + 'px';
        barLabel.style.left = (parseInt(rect.getAttribute('x')) + adjustXY) + 'px';
        index++;
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable, {
    timeline: {
      showBarLabels: false
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline"></div>
```

Comment: It almost worked! See answer below. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: This works but the text label will prevent the cell's tooltip to appear when you hover the mouse over the text.

Comment: barLabel.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; to fix the above issue

Answer (score 0):

I set attributes of '' and ' of '' for ocult text transforming it into an excerpt adjusted to the size of the bar.

Whether the text comes out from the left or from the right.

Attention!! That the element 'g' is the one that contains the 'rect' and 'text' of the bars in this

```
contenido[5]
```

Put this code after

```
dataTable.addRows();
```

Hope it helps you

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function() {
        var index = 0;
        var rects = []
        var contenido = container.getElementsByTagName('g');
        var xlat = 0
        var long = 0
        console.log("CONTENIDO",contenido);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(contenido[5].getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(valrect) {

            if (valrect.getAttribute('x') !== '0') {
                rects.push(valrect);
            }
        });
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(contenido[5].getElementsByTagName('text'), function(texted) {
            console.log("CAJA", rects[index]);
            console.log("TEXTO", texted)
            console.log("VALOR", texted.innerHTML)
            if (texted.getAttribute('x') !== '0') {
                var cajaWidth = parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) + parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('width'))
                if (parseInt(texted.getAttribute('x')) > cajaWidth ) {
                    var myDiv = texted.innerHTML;
                    long = parseInt((rects[index].getAttribute('width') / 8) - 2) ;
                    xlat = parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) + 10;
                    console.log("X",rects[index].getAttribute('x'));
                    console.log("XLAT", xlat);
                    texted.innerHTML = (myDiv.substring(0,long) + ' ...')
                    texted.setAttribute('x', xlat);
                    texted.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;  width: 120px;  white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden;  text-overflow: ellipsis;');
                }
                console.log("Condicion: ", parseInt(texted.getAttribute('x') - rects[index].getAttribute('x')))
                if (parseInt(texted.getAttribute('x')) < parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) ) {
                    var myDiv = texted.innerHTML;
                    long = parseInt((rects[index].getAttribute('width') / 8) - 4) ;
                    xlat = parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) + parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('width') - 15);
                    console.log("X",rects[index].getAttribute('x'));
                    console.log("XLAT", xlat);
                    texted.innerHTML = (myDiv.substring(0,long) + ' ...')
                    texted.setAttribute('x', xlat);
                    texted.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;  width: 120px;  white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden;  text-overflow: ellipsis;');
                }
                index++;
            }
        });
    });
    
   
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
        var index = 0;
        var rects = []
        var contenido = container.getElementsByTagName('g');
        var xlat = 0
        var long = 0
        console.log("CONTENIDO",contenido);
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(contenido[5].getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(valrect) {

            if (valrect.getAttribute('x') !== '0') {
                rects.push(valrect);
            }
        });
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(contenido[5].getElementsByTagName('text'), function(texted) {
            console.log("CAJA", rects[index]);
            console.log("TEXTO", texted)
            console.log("VALOR", texted.innerHTML)
            if (texted.getAttribute('x') !== '0') {
                var cajaWidth = parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) + parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('width'))
                if (parseInt(texted.getAttribute('x')) > cajaWidth ) {
                    var myDiv = texted.innerHTML;
                    long = parseInt((rects[index].getAttribute('width') / 8) - 2) ;
                    xlat = parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) + 10;
                    console.log("X",rects[index].getAttribute('x'));
                    console.log("XLAT", xlat);
                    texted.innerHTML = (myDiv.substring(0,long) + ' ...')
                    texted.setAttribute('x', xlat);
                    texted.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;  width: 120px;  white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden;  text-overflow: ellipsis;');
                }
                console.log("Condicion: ", parseInt(texted.getAttribute('x') - rects[index].getAttribute('x')))
                if (parseInt(texted.getAttribute('x')) < parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) ) {
                    var myDiv = texted.innerHTML;
                    long = parseInt((rects[index].getAttribute('width') / 8) - 4) ;
                    xlat = parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('x')) + parseInt(rects[index].getAttribute('width') - 15);
                    console.log("X",rects[index].getAttribute('x'));
                    console.log("XLAT", xlat);
                    texted.innerHTML = (myDiv.substring(0,long) + ' ...')
                    texted.setAttribute('x', xlat);
                    texted.setAttribute('style', 'display: block;  width: 120px;  white-space: nowrap;  overflow: hidden;  text-overflow: ellipsis;');
                }
                index++;
            }
        });
    });
```